# Should i assign JavaScript events directly just to unify code?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Am I programming poorly or bending backwards too much for IE by assigne event handlers like:

```
element.someEvent = someFunction;
```

instead of:

```
element.attachEventListener("someEvent", someFunction, false);
```

- What would be some cons and pros to this idea?
- What am i missing out or setting my self up to  by not just testing and choosing the proper method?

Comment: I appreciate all the input about jAuery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `element.onclick = xxx;` style, you're limiting yourself (and any other scripts you're using on the page) to a *single* event handler for the event on that element (any previous handler for that event gets bludgeoned). With the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` mechanism, you can attach and remove event handlers independently of one another, without cross-talk.

So for instance, if you do:

```
 document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function() {
 };
```

...then any previous `click` handler on element `foo` gets blown away and no longer called when `foo` is clicked. In contrast:

```
 document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function() {
 });
```

Now your `click` handler gets called, but any *other* `click` handlers that have previously been attached to the element *also* get called. You're playing nicely with others. :-)

It's easy to create a function that irons these things out for you:

```
function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
    if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
    }
    else if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else {
        element["on" + eventName] = handler;
    }
}
```

...or if you *really* want to go to town:

```
var hookEvent = (function() {

    function hookViaAttach(element, eventName, handler) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
    }
    function hookViaAdd(element, eventName, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    function hookDOM0(element, eventName, handler) {
        element["on" + eventName] = handler;
    }

    if (document.attachEvent) {
        return hookViaAttach;
    }
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        return hookViaAdd;
    }
    return hookDOM0;
})();
```

...which creates a function that detects *once* what kind of handler to use and then uses that throughout.

Frankly, though, for this stuff it's useful to leverage the work of others and use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Comment: Yes but cant i do, element.onclick = function(){}; and do whatever and as much as i want in the anonymous function?

Comment: @Babiker: Yes, you can -- and you bludgeon any previous event handler on the element.

Comment: However, in a simple enough web application, a single event handler may be perfectly acceptable.  The *correct* solution depends on the needs of the application.

Comment: Even if the event handler was of a different type?

Comment: @Babiker: No, you just overwrite any previous event handler **for that event** on that element.

Comment: @Babiker: If you assign to `onclick`, you blow away any other `click` handlers but not handlers for, say, `mousemove`. But with the DOM2 mechanism (as `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` is called), there can be *multiple* `click` handlers on the same element.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: thanks. @T.J Crowder: If i could give tow up votes for the second part of you answer i would be a happy man :D

Comment: @Babiker, no it will only destroy the handler for the same type on the same element. The problem is when your code gets large / you start using other people's code, that you don't realise that a handler was attached already.

Answer (score 1):

If you have full control over the page, and you're sure that all event binding happens in one place, then .onevent is the simplest and most supported way.

If you're worried about overriding a previous event handler, you can always do:

```
var oldOnclick = el.onclick;
el.onclick = function () {
   // blah blah
   if (oldOnclick) oldOnclick();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you need to use attachEvent. (The standard DOM mechanism is addEventListener.) I would highly recommend using a library like jQuery that takes care of these browser differences for you. Frameworks like jQuery also take care of ironing out the differences between the event models in different browsers.

Comment: @James Kovacs, Oh trust me, am a beginner and i am in this for the long, run i wouldn't use jQuery to save my life :D

Comment: @Babiker: If you have a problem with jQuery, fair 'nuff, but look into your other options (I gave you a list, and a link to a longer one). There are a **lot** of browser-specific workarounds and other "gotchas" that other people have already run into, debugged, and worked around. It's in your best interest to leverage that work rather than repeating it.

Comment: @Babiker Not sure why being a beginner / in it for the long run makes you say that. It depends what you want to do. If your goal is to build functional websites, then jQuery is far more practical and lets you focus on actually building your features.

Comment: @T.J Crowder, @box8: I dont have any problem with jQuery or any other library, but i would rather struggle and learn pure JavaScript instead of spending time sharpening my jQuery skills.

Comment: Couldn't agree with TJ and box9 more. Why waste your time solving problems that others have already solved? It's good to understand those solutions (and therefore study the jQuery source code - and other frameworks too), but there are enough unsolved problems in the world than figuring out AGAIN why IE is leaking memory when deleting DOM nodes and you haven't unhooked your event handlers - just to pick a random example. All browsers have their quirks. Build on the work of those before you.

Comment: @Babiker: *"i would rather struggle and learn pure JavaScript"* **Absolutely!** And glad to hear it. But this has nothing to do with learning the ins and outs of JavaScript, which is a wonderful rich language that it's well worth learning the ins and outs of. It's about dealing with the herd of wild cats we call web browsers, and how each of them interprets (or ignores) specifications around the DOM and events and invents their own way of doing things. Learning their bugs/issues/peccadillos is frankly a waste of time you could spend doing something useful... *(cont'd)*

Comment: @Babiker I don't want to keep beating at the same point, and it's fair enough if you really want to delve into all the DOM differences, but remember that what you're learning is BROWSER DOM differences, not "pure javascript", especially if you consider server-side javascript which is completely detached from the DOM. Personally I think jQuery (and other libraries, the concepts translate quite well) has taught me much more about the *better parts* of the JS language than the browser quirks have or will. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: @Babiker: *(continuing)* ...something useful like, say, **really** learning the JavaScript language in all its richness, which will serve you well regardless of which (if any) libraries you use to smooth over browser weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there are many javascript library out there that will take care of the cross browsers compatibility for you and also make coding in javascript fun. One of the most popular one out there is [Jquery](http://jquery.com/).

You can register events with Jquery like so:

```
$(elem).click(function () {
    alert('Event handler');
});

or 

$(elem).bind('click', function() {
    alert('Event handler');
});
```