# Override standard method called by double click event in CRM grid.

Tags: javascript, events, grid, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Following situation in CRM 2011: My goal is to show several entities in one grid. Therefore we made a wrapper entity which links to the real entity (wrapper entity to entity A, B, C). When an item in A, B or C is created, also an wrapper entity item is created by a plugin. 
Like this I can have a grid, "mixing" all the entities, while in fact only show the items of the wrapper entity.

But of course, if I do a double click or right click -> open in this grid, I don't want to open the wrapper entity item, I directly want to open the window of e.g. entity A item. Ribbon Button is no problem btw.

I followed two routes so far:

a) Link replacement: After the grid is loaded I went through the DOM and replaced the oid, otype and otypename with the values of the (real) target item (entity A, B or C). This idea has a two downsides: first when to execute the replacement routine (only on load is not enough as its possible to sort, filter or flip pages later). Second and man problem are the ribbon buttons. I want to delete the wrapper entity items and not the invoice behind it. Things get confused when I replace all those IDs. I would have to replace all the buttons by custom buttons.

b) Method/Event replacement: it would be elegant to just replace the event where the item detail window is called. Unfortunately I didn't figure out yet how the events are implemented in CRM, I was hoping to unattach an event and replace it by mine, but this seems to be a hidden secret. CRMWeb_static_grid\AppGrid_DefaultData.htc has the dblclick-event, but I don't understand if this is the one I'm looking for and how to unattach.

Has anyone ever tried to replace an event handler in a crm grid or got an idea how it might work?

Hope it's clear what I mean...

Thank you very much for any idea.

Comment: I hope you know that this will be an unsupported customisation

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't see any way to achieve this in a supported way.

Comment: This is best approached by creating a web resource that displays the "wrapper" entities, but makes the link to the correct form. That would be completely supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events in the interface are handled the same way IE handles all [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) events (see the SO question [Should i assign JavaScript events directly just to unify code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340547/should-i-assign-javascript-events-directly-just-to-unify-code) for just one example).

A functionality for overriding the default doubleclick action might start as follows:

```js
function Load() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("myGridName");
    grid.ondblclick = DoubleClickAction;
}

function DoubleClickAction() {
    var id, url;
    //get the id of the entity in the row you double clicked
    id = GetId();

    //generate the entity form url
    url = GetUrl();

    //open the record window
    OpenRecordWindow(url);
}

function OpenRecordWindow(url) {
    var url;

    if (Xrm.Page.context.isOutlookClient()) {
        openStdWin(url, "Your Title", "width=1024,height=768,status=1");
    }
    else {
        window.open(url);
    }

}
```

---

**Edit:** Based on your comments, you're getting into some pretty serious customization of the DOM here. You'd have to change the `dblclick` event for each row in the grid *whenever the grid refreshes* since the right click event is based on the row's `dblclick` event. So you'd have to find the grid and also attach a `refresh` event to the grid that attaches a `dblclick` event to any found rows.

To get the id of the grid, and the potential ids of any rows, you can use IE's F12 developer tools to browse/search through the HTML.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that with ondblclick the old event is overwritten. So I don't have to particulary remove the old event, just attach the new one, this is good. However, I still struggle to find the right place where to attach the event. The event is defined in a htc-file ("AppGrid_DefaultData.htc") and then bound in via a class ("ms-crm-List-Data") to the gridBodyTable.
I will to some reading about the htc-files and write later my conclusions.

Thank you

Comment: In the "open" event in the right click on the grid calls the double click event of the parent row:
onclick="if(!disabled){parentRow.fireEvent('ondblclick');parentPopup.hide();}"
So hopefully no changes needed there to override the standard function after double click is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Can you display this data by joining A to B and A to C? How are these three entities related? A to B and A to C? A to B to C?

I ask because you should be able to achieve your goal with the standard join functionality provided by Views and avoid this override business altogether. If you have to setup some relationships between the entities just for this view it is probably preferred to a wrapper entity.

(I would prefer to add this as a comment... I dont think I have enough reputation)

Comment: Well, they are different tables , so with a view it would only be possible to load field from other tables AFAIK?

There might be a relation between A, B and C, but does not have to. E.g. A knows the id of B and B knows the id of C, but A does not know the id of C directly of course. They are mainly linked via the wrapper entity.