# Detach Event originating from htc File

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dynamics-crm-2011, dhtml

I have htc-file from where events (public:attach event) are loaded. In my case I want to disable/detach the ondblclick-event which is loaded from the htc file. Finally it is a grid from where the event is fired, in the expando there are the options given to the target method.

When I go through the element tree I can't find the event attached to any element, so I am a little bit confused where to find it and where to detach/overwrite it. The event is called by "firevent" at several places.

Any idea how to get rid of it?

(The htc file I am talking about is Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb_static_grid\AppGrid_DefaultData.htc, I try to solve this problem: 
[Override standard method called by double click event in CRM grid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330482/override-standard-method-called-by-double-click-event-in-crm-grid) but thought this might be good as it's own topic)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remove a DHTML event:

- The [removeBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536700) method
- Reset the HTC to a dummy URL, such as `behavior:url(foo.htc)`