# Override default behaviour in CRM 2013 grid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I need to be able to open entities to a new window in CRM 2013 rather than use the default behaviour of opening in the current window.  This is because clicking the back button removes the filters and sorts on the datagrid and you have to start again.

I've seen this method [Override standard method called by double click event in CRM grid.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330482/override-standard-method-called-by-double-click-event-in-crm-grid) but it doesn't seem to work in CRM 2013 (either that or I am getting the name of the grid wrong).

It doesn't have to be a supported solution, just one that does what I need it to, i.e. open a record in a new window when the grid is double clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unsupported:**
Changing line 507  in _static/_common/scripts/main.js into the following piece of code causes the record to popout. This uses the same popout function inside the entity form.

```
//rollup2 - line 507 after beautification 
//Update: rollup3 - line 566 after beautification 
if (this.get_contentUrl().get_pageType() == "entityrecord")
     popOutSourceUrl($v_0); //taken from globl.ashx line 12027
else
     this.$3_3.get_currentIFrame().contentWindow.location.replace($v_0);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to do this without overriding the behaviour like this? possibly by detaching the event and then attaching my own?

Comment: You can use the following approach that re-evaluates the command bar and simulates a grid change event. 
http://develop1.net/public/post/The-cream-cracker-conundrum-%28or-customising-the-sub-grid-command-bar%29.aspx