# dynamics crm get name of subgrid on associated view

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

When I open the contact form and then select activities from the navigation bar, the associated activities view appears. Is there a way to get the name of the subgrid for this view? I

```
var subgrid = Xrm.Page.getControl(<sub-grid name>);
```

Comment: That’s not subgrid. That’s associated view. You can find the name using browser developer toolbar..

Comment: Thanks. What I am actually trying to achieve is open the record in a new form when they select the row (with a single click) in the associated grid view. I found the name which is an ID for the div element, but this returns null when trying to retrieve the control Xrm.Page.getControl method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This is unsupported customization.

Getting Associated view grid is different from subgrid in entity forms. Subgrid in CRM form is accessible using `Xrm.Page.getControl(subgrid_name)` like any other control.

But to access Associated view grid, you have to do DOM manipulation starting from IFRAME, then Grid like below.

To get the IFrame control:

```
var frame = document.frames[“areaActivitiesFrame”].frameElement;
```

To refresh the associated grid view:

```
frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById(“crmGrid_Account_ActivityPointers”).control.refresh();
```

Once you get the control, try to override the click event like explained in [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9330482/7920473)